# Bezier Path Not Drawing on context

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying give my user fine selection of a point they touch on a UIImage.
I have a magnifying square in the top left corner that shows where they're touching at 2x zoom. It works well.

I'm trying to add a "crosshair" in the center of the magnifying area to make selection clearer.

With the code below no line is visible.

```
//Bulk of the magifying code    
public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2, 2)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -self.touchPoint.x, -self.touchPoint.y)
        drawLine(context)
        self.viewToMagnify.layer.renderInContext(context)
}
//Code for drawing horizontal line of crosshair
private func drawLine(ctx: CGContext) {
    let lineHeight: CGFloat = 3.0
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * 0.3
    let horizontalPath = UIBezierPath()
    horizontalPath.lineWidth = lineHeight
    let hStart = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 - lineWidth/2, y:bounds.height/2)
    let hEnd = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2 + lineWidth/2,y:bounds.height/2)
    horizontalPath.moveToPoint(hStart)
    horizontalPath.addLineToPoint(hEnd)
    UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
    horizontalPath.stroke()
}
```

It's possible that the line **is** being drawn but too small or not where I expect it to be.

I've tried other ways of drawing the line like using `CGContextAddPath`

I think the issue might be related to the `renderInContextView` not taking my drawing into account, or I'm not adding the path to the context correctly?

The magnification code is based on [GJNeilson's work](https://github.com/GJNilsen/YPMagnifyingGlass), all I've done is pin the centre point of the magnifying glass to the top left and remove the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're drawing the line then drawing the image over it. Try calling `drawLine` last.

Also, the scale and translate are still active when you draw the line which may be positioning it offscreen. You might have to reset it using `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState`

Comment: They both sound like a good candidate! My Macbook started an update when my back was turned! I'll let you know when I've tried it out.

Comment: It was the saving and restoring of the state that made it work. As you say it must have been positioning it elsewhere.
Thanks for your time.